# bash script wildcard not globbing files

Tags: bash, wildcard

I have a script where I am switching from the apparently bad practice of populating arrays with `find` or `ls` to using globs.

I recently got a report from a user where the expression is not globbing the files.. The user has a different Linux distro than I, but the script is being called by `GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release` in both cases. I have tried a bunch of different variations which work in my shell but not in theirs. Here is the latest:

```
 declare -a ARRAY
 GLOB="keyword"
 VAR=("path/to/file/*${GLOB}*")
 ARRAY+=("$VAR")
```

However the my logs indicate that

```
$ echo ${ARRAY[*]}
  path/to/file/*keyword*
```

With unexpanded wildcards, instead of the expected/desired

```
$ echo ${ARRAY[*]}
  13_keyword_$23.txt
  14_keyword_$24.txt
  ...
```

The `VAR` path is populated with variables, but it is expanding correctly and the files **are** present. The directory holds a bunch of files like `17_keyword_$22.txt`.

I wonder if someone can tell me what I am missing so I can count on inter-bash portability. I have had several slightly different versions of this work on my machine but not the other, and am wondering what environmental variable might be causing the disconnect. I have not added any `shopt noglob` options to the script, I just double quote all file path related variables. Could that be it?

**Edit**: also tried simply

```
 ARRAY+=(path/to/file/*'keyword'*.txt
```

or

```
GLOB=(path/to/file/*keyword*)
ARRAY+=("$GLOB")
```

Which worked only for my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting a wildcard inhibits globbing.

```
VAR=("path/to/file/"*"$GLOB"*)
```

But you'll need to fix all the other problems as well.

Comment: my original implementation was simply ```ARRAY+=(path/to/file/*'keyword'*.txt)```. The single quotes were vestigal from an early need and later were removed. This worked on my shell but not theirs, and the quotes were not around wildcards. I am missing something, that is clear. Then I went with ```GLOB=(path/to/file/*keyword*); ARRAY+=("$GLOB")```, which was the same

Comment: Yes, that's because the next problem is that that's not how you express an existing array as an array.

Comment: okay, I guess I had a different problem than the one I was trying to solve. Thanks, I will look at that. I was just trying to add those files to the existing array. I should have thought of that, it isn;t how I usually do it. But I saw it somewhere and thought it looked handy, and short.

Comment: I could go into the comedy of errors that got me here, but instead I will say thanks and accept. Thanks.

Comment: Just to add another bit of confusion: `echo ${ARRAY[*]}` will expand any remaining globs after substituting the array's value but before printing it. If you want to get at the elements of an array without any confusing post-processing, use `"${VAR[@]}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update, it turned out that the problem in my actual script (not the cruddy mock-up above) was that the globbing was not working because of the formatting of the user's partition.

I had fine results with ext3, ext4 and fat32. But NTFS formatted partitions handled the globbing differently. At least, I think it was the globbing that is the problem. I have not fixed the original issue yet, but at least I can simply recommend a different partition.

I will continue to accept the earlier answer since it accurately answered the question as written.

Thanks!